Firebase Test Lab instrumentation Test for Android App - Prevent tests being counted as sessions/new users in Firebase / GA statistics
I have run my first Test Lab Instrumentation Test on my Android App via Firebase by uploading my debug.apk and selecting some virtual and real devices to test on. The test itself ran through successfully.
Problem: The activities/sessions generated by these test are unfortunately counted as regular sessions in google analytics / firebase, distorting all the statistics, e.g., on new users, active users. Also, a crash of a (very old) test device is now counted towards crashes in firebase crashlytics.
Expected behaviour: When testing my app via emulator or on my phone in debug mode, these sessions/actions are not included in firebase... This is essentially how I would like to have it for the automation tests as well.
This is how I register firebase in main:
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

And this is how I prevent registering activities in debug mode in main:
  if (kDebugMode) {
    await firebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false);
  }

Why does this not work when I upload my debug.apk to Firebase Test Lab Instrumentation Test? What do I need to change?

Test sessions shouldn't hamper your Firebase Analytics and Crashlytics data for that use Custom Debug Flag. Add a boolean in your BuildConfig class set it true when running tests and false during actual user usage, i.e in production.

So, you are saying I need to change a variable in the code before uploading the apk to Firebase Test Lab? It cannot identify that I upload a debug.apk and prevent this on its own, correct? Ok, let me read up on the BuildConfig and try this approach. I am just confused, because when running the debug.apk on my phone, it will identify this by default and by way of my posted code handle it correctly. And the test lab should essentially be doing exactly the same thing?

1. Set Flag
Add flag named IS_TEST_RUN in project level build.gradle :
android {
  defaultConfig {
    applicationId 
    minSdkVersion 
    targetSdkVersion 
    versionCode 
    versionName 
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    // Add the new field & keep it false by default 
    boolean IS_TEST_RUN = false 
    
  }
  // ... other configurations
}

2. Add check
Handle flag in your activity :
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        // Check the flag before logging events
        if (!BuildConfig.IS_TEST_RUN) {
            FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.APP_OPEN, null);
        }
    }
}

FirebaseAnalytics.logEvent is only called if IS_TEST_RUN is false.
3. Set true :
You can set it true for testing use command :
./gradlew test -PisTestRun=true

Generate bundle for firebase while providing build for testing use command :
./gradlew bundleRelease -PisTestRun=true


Note :
You can create a custom Gradle task if you need to do more operations while flag is true.
But that will be more complex :
project level build.gradle
tasks.register("setTestFlag") {
    doLast {
        // Logic to set IS_TEST_RUN flag (e.g., using a file or environment variable)
    }
}

You can set actions to be done in doLast block, while that task is being performed.
By above described method flag can be set to true for IS_TEST_RUN to perform release bundle generation using Gradle commands without add more complexity to build variant like adding multiple productFlavors.
Reference links :

https://developer.android.com/build

https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html



Hi Bob, many thanks for your detailed answer. I wasn't expected that I need to go into the build grade for this... For a Gradle newbie like me please clarify: I am currently building the APK via terminal with the command "flutter build apk --debug". 1) Where would I use the ./gradlew command, I have never used it (windows, visual studio code)? 2) I understand that this would be an additional flag to use when compiling the APK? 3) Where do I use the myactivity class, I don't have this as well... Wouldnt it be easier to use the flag to set analytics enable false (see my code below)...


If you are facing difficulty while executing gradlew command, just set IS_TEST_RUN flag true/false in file while providing build to your users or firebase.  2. If you follow my 1st point then this point will not be applicable 3. myactivity  class is just for reference it was demonstration purpose only use wherever you are using analytics but just put check of if (!BuildConfig.IS_TEST_RUN) and do analytics logging. Happy to Help. Hope I made you clear now. Consider accepting and upvoting.

